# MySQL: Is AUTO_INCREMENT always unique now?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have code created in time of MySQL 3.23.23
At that time MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT reused smallest released AUTO_INCREMENT values.

It could generate 
100, 101, 102, 103,

delete 101

**101**, 104, 105

and we used special table to generate IDs, by LOCKING table, `UPDATE IDTABLE SET id = id + 1 WHERE key = 'table_name'; SELECT id ... ; UNLOCK;`

According to mysql docs such extra table is not requirement any more. But how is it reliable to rely on MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Is AUTO_INCREMENT behavior storage engine specific?
Is it described in SQL specs?

These IDs are very important they must increase and be unique even if old records are deleted. (like order number in shopping cart software)

---

May be the problem was as karancan say

insert 100, 101, 102, 103, **104**

delete **104**

insert **104**, 105, 106

We definitely had some sort of bug with AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL 10 year ago.
We can delete all records but AUTO_INCREMENT must stay.

That is why I ask about it.

Comment: As long as you do not run a query having `SET AUTO_INCREMENT=xx`, this should be reliable. I never faced a problem with that. Specs by the way http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I've been using MySQL since version 3 (the first public release) and never found the behaviour you describe. Do you have a link about that?

Comment: I can't find link. I know that we had such problem 10 years ago and now I wish to get rid of that complex code. It hard decision to modify code that worked well 10 years. originally we used AUTO_INCREMENT and then switched to LOCKS